# How to add conditionals or filters to a solr terms query for autosuggest

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I've implemented a solr terms query for an auto suggest component.

This is how a regular query looks like:

https://myserver.com/solr/mydata/terms?omitHeader=true&wt=json&json.nl=flat&terms=true&terms.regex=.%2my search term%2A&terms.limit=20&terms.fl=location&terms.fl=price&terms.fl=state&terms.fl=city&terms.fl=country&terms.fl=id&terms.regex.flag=case_insensitive

Now my client would like to filter the results based on different criteria like location=XXX or product-price > xxx. So far I cant find a way to achieve it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use faceting instead? That will give you the terms based on what's being returned from an actual query - including any filter queries.

Comment: @MatsLindh can you please provide an example? maybe translating the current query from terms to faceting?